# Carga temprana de datos de una tercera tabla en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo 3 modelos Eloquent.

- Usuarios
- roles
- empleados.
- Un usuario puede tener un rol.
- Usuarios y empleados se corresponden 1 a 1.
- Hay una FK de usuarios a roles y otra de empleados a usuarios.

Puedo obtener el rol de un empleado con:

```
$employee->user->role;
```

Puedo cargar con *eager-loading* el usuario de cada empleado:

```
Employee::with('user')->get();
```

¿Puedo cargar con *eager-loading* también el rol para el empleado?

Comment: Debería poderse *según lo que entiendo de tu escenario* con hacer esto: `Employee::with('user.roles')->get();` donde *roles* sería el nombre de la relación (*ese nombre claramente puede cambiar según lo hayas declarado*)

Comment: @BetaM `Employee::with('user.role')->get();` en este caso. Sí, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La relación entre Empleado y Roles no existe de manera directa, pero podemos invocarla por medio de la relación de Empleado con Usuarios.

De modo que la consulta pudiera ser de esta forma:

```
Modelo::with('relacionDirecta.RelacionAnidada')
```

Y la consulta final nos quedaría de esta forma:

```
Employee::with('user.role')->get();
```

- Aquí puedes leer mas sobre [relaciones anidadas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)